# Outsider vs. Odd-man-out

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

Which is a better choice:

> Moreover, reckoning with unpopular and very minor sub-disciplines of science for many years, specialists are being left as **outsiders** in the society — with a significant disability in making their ideas interesting for a wide range of public audiences.

Or

> Moreover, reckoning with unpopular and very minor sub-disciplines of science for many years, specialists are being left as **odd-men-out** in the society — with a significant disability in making their ideas interesting for a wide range of public audiences.

Comment: I don't believe *odd-men-out* ever works.  It is a bit oxymoronic.  An odd-man-out is a single outlier, different from the pack.  Would you like to join my *loner* support group?  It's a group where people who prefer to be alone can get together and discuss their feelings with a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer "outsider" as being more formal and therefore fitting better in the style of the context (which itself has minor problems of style) you have given. Also, "odd-men-out" may distract people interested in gender issues from the message you are trying to get across.

Comment: Would you please tell me where the minor problems are?